# Setting x & y on ToolTip.Show somehow sets duration as well?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

When I call ToolTip.Show() like below;

```
ToolTip.Show(Message, MyControl);
```

Everything works perfectly, it shows and goes away when MyControl looses focus. However the position of the ToolTip is over MyControl so I want to add an offset;

```
ToolTip.Show(Message,MyControl,10,-20);
```

The ToolTip does position the way I want, it shows when hovering over, but is does not disappear anymore on MyControl loosing focus. The behaviour is similar to setting the duration very high.

When I look at the ToolTip.Show() definition, one of the ways to call it is like this;

```
public void Show(string text, IWin32Window window, int x, int y);
```

So how can the ToolTip suddenly stop disappearing when I only add the x & y offset and not touch the duration?

Below the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFA
{
  public class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        UC UC = new UC();
        this.Controls.Add(UC);
    }
  }

  public class UC : UserControl
  {
    String Message = "Hello!";
    PictureBox MyControl = new PictureBox();
    ToolTip ToolTip = new ToolTip();

    public UC()
    {
        MyControl.ImageLocation = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR5ih.png";
        MyControl.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        this.Controls.Add(MyControl);
        MyControl.MouseHover += ShowToolTip;
    }

    private void ShowToolTip(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip.Show(Message, MyControl,10,-20); // this will never disappear??
      //ToolTip.Show(Message, MyControl); // this disappears after leaving
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `MyControl` parented by a Form when you call `ToolTip.Show`?

Comment: It is in a UserControl that is loaded into a statusbar of an external program

Comment: How can you add control to external program? Is that a plugin? Or how? Can you post a short but complete sample to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Hey Sriram, that doesn't matter, I added code that will demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you don't specify any "Timeout", ToolTip will be hidden only when the parent form is deactivated.

If you want to hide the tooltip when mouse leaves your control you've to manually do it by calling `ToolTip.Hide`.

```
public UC()
{
    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    MyControl.ImageLocation = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR5ih.png";
    MyControl.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    this.Controls.Add(MyControl);
    MyControl.MouseHover += ShowToolTip;

    //Subscribe MouseLeave and hide the tooltip there
    MyControl.MouseLeave += MyControl_MouseLeave;
}

void MyControl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip.Hide(MyControl);
}
```

Comment: Hey Sriram, but in the case where I use ToolTip.Show(Message, MyControl) I also do not specify the Timeout, but is still works perfectly without having to subscribe to MouseLeave? So I still don't get it?

Comment: @Bastiaan It is quite complicated my friend. When you don't pass the location, with your code, the tooltip will move following your mouse. Every overload behaves different. When you pass the location, tooltip won't follow your mouse. You need to hide and show it if you want it to follow. There are so many convoluted things. I manually hide it whenever I use tooltip and that's what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you should use
ToolTip.Show(string text, IWin32Window window, int x, int y,int duration);

Comment: why? I do not want to change the duration and according to the definition I do not need to..